# Angular Form Email Validator not working as expected

Tags: angular, validation

I have a very simple form with just one input field:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  emailAddress: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="emailAddress">
```

This field has two validators, required and for emails.

I also have a submit button that is configured as follows:

```
<button [disabled]="!form.valid" type="submit">Send</button>
```

The confusing part is that when I input a wrong email address like:

> a@b

the submit button gets enabled, thus marking the form and input field as valid. I expect that `a@b` is not a valid email address.

Is there any other Email Validator in angular that I should use or is this a bug?

Comment: It is a valid email address. Not a common one, sure, but a valid one.

Comment: If it doesn't suit your case, I suggest you look online for regexes (`pattern` validator). For instance : http://emailregex.com/

Comment: Common is `a@b.c`. Why not make it work like that and use regex for the exceptions? Now it is almost useless.

Answer (score 13):

You can use pattern to implement valid email

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            firstName: ['', Validators.required],
            lastName: ['', Validators.required],
            email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email,Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')]],
            password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
        });
    }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-validation

Comment: I cannot get the point on using `Validators.email` if we are to enter a pattern manually. In it's documentation it says that it applies a regex pattern to validate it.

Comment: Angular uses whatwg version of regex for email validation you can check more infor here https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address

Answer (score 6):

You can use custom email validation

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-email-validator-not-working-as-expected?file=app/select-overview-example.html)**

> Component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="emailAddress" placeholder="Enter email">
    <button [disabled]="!myForm.valid" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

> Component.ts

```
myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      emailAddress: [null, [Validators.required, this.emailValidator]]
    });
  }

  emailValidator(control) {
    if (control.value) {
      const matches = control.value.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/);
      return matches ? null : { 'invalidEmail': true };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

for angular just add the atribute "email" like this :

```
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" #email="ngModel"
       ngModel class="form-control" email required>
<span class="help-block" *ngIf="!email.valid && email.touched">
     Email is invalid
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a valid email address and so why it pass validation. If it does not satisfy, you can create your own validator and implement your logic there.

You can read more [**Custom Validators**](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-custom-validator/) and try to implement yours.